# Why This Code Give me Error in if Statment

Tags: java, helper

Why  give  me  error  in Extra  word  in if  statment  only

```
switch (Class) {
  case 'F':
       value = 30;
       Extra = Weight-value ;
       break ;
  case 'B':
      value = 25 ;
      Extra = Weight - value ;

      break ;

   case 'E':
       value = 20 ;
       Extra = Weight - value ;

       break;
    default  :
        System.out.println("You  Not  Enter The  Right Class ");
}
System.out.println("Extra is " );

if ( Extra >=0 )
{
    Total = Extra * 10 ;
    System.out.println("You Have Extra  weight "+Extra +"And You Should Pay "+Total );

}

else
{
    System.out.println("No  Extra Weight to Pay Your  Weight is   "+Weight);
}
```

Comment: Please include the entire code.

Comment: This probably because `Extra` may never be initialized, add default value in `default` clause of the `switch` statement

Comment: And describe what error you are getting (for example by including the error message). Also according to the Java Code Convention variables are supposed to start with a lower case characters only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you're trying to use the value of `Extra`, but it's possible that `Extra` has never been assigned a value (if `Class` isn't `'F'`, `'B'`, or `'C'`, so the `default` path through the `switch` is followed). Before being used, a local variable must definitely be assigned a value.

---

I strongly recommend following standard [Java naming conventions](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html). Local variables should not start with an uppercase character.